# PM2 start creates strange files

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

i created a simple "bot" for parsing a rss-feed into some trello-cards.

I'm using pm2 for starting and maintaining the bot.js

For some strange reason the cliframework creates some strange files.

Just to make the situation as clear as possible:

```
pm2 list
```

returns

```
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ bot      │ 0  │ fork │ 25084 │ online │ 0       │ 3m     │ 0%  │ 67.7 MB   │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

sometimes if i'm using the

```
ls
```

the command is returning

```
bot.js  node_modules
```

and sometime it returns with 1+ additional empty files like these

```
b0d3e000-bca5-11e6-b57b-fff3b35ba082  b0d3e001-bca5-11e6-b57b-fff3b35ba082  
bot.js  node_modules
```

the files are getting deleted some secons afterwards and getting created with different names some seconds afterwards

here is the main problem:

This bot was running for 3 weeks while i was absence and on restart counter there was a 3127 (why this much... idk) but for every restart there was a such a file left.. i had to delete 3127 files.. just because pm2 is creating some strange files..

is there any other similar issue listed yet.. or do you know a possible fix or explanation for this?

edit: i just realized that these files are not created from restarting.. because they are there now without restart counter > 0

just to make sure, the code broken down:

```js
var feed = require('feed-read');
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var utf8 = require('utf8');
var sprintf = require('sprintf-js').sprintf;

var UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = "Unable to connect.";
var CURFEED = "";
var PUBDATE = new Array();
var FEEDS = new Array();
FEEDS["TEST"] = "http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed?unit=second&interval=4"; //test

var LISTID = new Array();
LISTID["TEST"] = "TRELLO_COLUMN";

var Trello = require("node-trello");
var t = new Trello("", "");

(function() {

  var timeout = setInterval(function() {
    async.parallel([ function(callback) {
        CURFEED = "TEST";
        feedMe(CURFEED);
        // TODO: where to call callback()?
    } ], function done(err, results) {
        console.log("Done");
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
  }, 1000);
})();

function feedMe(feedName){

  if(FEEDS[feedName] == "" || FEEDS[feedName] == undefined){
      return;
  }
  feed(FEEDS[feedName], "ISO-8859-16", function(err, articles) {
      // console.log("------------------------- " + FEEDS[feedName]);
      if (err) {
          // html.push("<p>", UNABLE_TO_CONNECT = "</p>");
          console.log(UNABLE_TO_CONNECT);
      } else {
        var updated = false;
        var newArticle = new Array();
          articles.forEach(function(entry) {
              var merkDate = new Date(entry.published);
              var oldDate = new Date(PUBDATE[feedName]);

              if(PUBDATE[feedName] == "" || PUBDATE[feedName] == undefined){
                PUBDATE[feedName] = merkDate;
              }

              if(oldDate.getTime() < merkDate.getTime()){
                updated = true;
                newArticle.push(entry);
              }
          });

          if(newArticle.length > 0){
            for (var i = newArticle.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              var entry = newArticle[i];

              console.log(sprintf("----------------------------------------------------------"));
              console.log(sprintf("> %1$s %2$s: %3$s", "New-RSS-Entry", "detected", "Checking"));
              console.log(sprintf("---%1$s %2$s: %3$s", "Entry-Name", "", entry.title));
              console.log(sprintf("----%1$s %2$s: %3$s", "Link-Name", "", entry.link));
              console.log(sprintf("--%1$s %2$s: %3$s", "Create-Date", "", entry.published));
              console.log(sprintf("-------%1$s %2$s: %3$s", "Status", "", "Creating-Trello-Card"));

              t.post("/1/lists/"+LISTID[feedName]+"/cards", {name: entry.title, desc: entry.link} , function(err, data){
                 t.put("/1/cards/"+data.id+"/pos", {value: 0}, function(err, data){
                 });
              });

              console.log(sprintf("-------%1$s %2$s: %3$s", "Status", "", "Trello-Card fully created"));
              console.log(sprintf("> %1$s %2$s: %3$s", "New-RSS-Entry", "detected", "Closing"));
            }
          }

          if(updated == true){
            PUBDATE[feedName] = new Date();
          }

      }
  });
}
```

Comment: May be possible while configuring pm2 it set temporary file if there is any issue or error??

Comment: I don't know where this configuration should be... The documentary says nothing about the files either

Comment: Could you add the command you're using to start bot.js with pm2?

Comment: just a simple `pm2 start bot.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i investigated the files and got the solution now.
Just don't use `require('feed-read')` anymore.

It seems like creating files to encode it and stream it afterwards.

The main problems are the following:

- Rss feed got a wrong syntax
- Server is unavailable
- Server returning a db error or something

If one of the things above happen, the file won't be deleted afterwards. Some of 'em were empty. But i found a vBulletinRss feed which returned the "DB Error".

To round that up just use a request and parse it yourself.